# Alfresco explorer and multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, alfresco

I want to export some database results in a .xls and I want to do it in an another Thread. When I create the Thread it executes well but when I'm trying to get the childNode of the space it returns null but if I don't use the thread the program do it well.

This is the code of the class who calls thread and do the export:

```
public class ExportarResultadosExcellActionBean {

...

 public void iniciaHilo(final ActionEvent event){
        HiloExportaExcell hilo = new HiloExportaExcell(event, this.nodeService);
        Thread t = new Thread(hilo);
        t.start();
    }

...

private List<NodeRef> recuperarUnidadesDidacticas(final NodeRef campaniaNodeRef) throws Exception {

        List<NodeRef> unidadesOrdenadasList = new ArrayList<NodeRef>();
        try {
            // Recuperar las Unidad Didáctica de la Unidad Didáctica de la Campaña
            Set<QName> childNodeUnidadQNames = new HashSet<QName>();
            childNodeUnidadQNames.add(ContentModelEvaluacion.TYPE_UN_DIDACTICA);
            **List<ChildAssociationRef> unidadesList =
                this.nodeService.getChildAssocs(campaniaNodeRef, childNodeUnidadQNames);**

...
```

And this is the code of HiloExportaExcell.class

```
public class HiloExportaExcell extends Thread {
    private ActionEvent evento;
    private transient NodeService node;

    public HiloExportaExcell(ActionEvent event, NodeService nodeservice){
        this.evento = event;
        this.setNode(nodeservice);
    }
    public void run(){
        ExportarResultadosExcellActionBean exportaExcell = new ExportarResultadosExcellActionBean();

        exportaExcell.setNodeService(this.getNode());
        exportaExcell.exportar(evento);
    }
    public NodeService getNode() {
        return node;
    }
    public void setNode(NodeService node) {
        this.node = node;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to work in another thread you (most likely) need to make sure security- and transactional context are set up appropriately. You can either do that yourself:

```
        AuthenticationUtil.runAs(new AuthenticationUtil.RunAsWork<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object doWork() throws Exception {
                getRetryingTransactionHelper().doInTransaction(new RetryingTransactionHelper.RetryingTransactionCallback<Object>() {
                    @Override
                    public Object execute() throws Throwable {
                        // do stuff here
                        return null; 
                    }
                });
                return null;
            }
        }, AuthenticationUtil.getFullyAuthenticatedUser());
```

Or create an action and execute it asynchronously by calling `ActionService.executeAction` with proper parameters.

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that the behaviour arises from transactional isolation. When you perfrom the following steps:

- start a transaction (maybe automatically by framework)
- create a new node
- create a second thread

Then the second thread won't be able to see the new node. This is not an error but a consequence of transactional semantics ... and from the implementation of transactional contexts by Spring.

Everything should work as expected if you start your second tread *after* the transaction in thread one commits.